# How to dynamically update documents with Mongoose in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, mongoose

I need to update attributes from a MongoDB document based on the value from the `data-target` from an HTML object. However, I don't know how to insert its `data-target` in the `JSON.stringify`

```
const save = (_id) =>{
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    const saves= document.querySelectorAll(".flaticon-diskette")

    saves.forEach(function(save){

        console.log(`.input-${save.getAttribute("data-target")}`)
        const input = document.querySelector(`.input-${save.getAttribute("data-target")}`)
        var target = save.getAttribute("data-target")

        save.addEventListener('click', () =>{
            fetch(`https://janfa.gharsnull.now.sh/api/auth/edit/${_id}`,{
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    authorization : token,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify( { target : `${input.value}`} ), 
            }).then(console.log("done"))
        })
    })
}
```

`target` is supposed to contain the `data-target` of each `save` but instead it's read as "target" by `JSON.stringify`. I tried using a template strings, but it seems like `JSON.stringify` won't let me use it in the first field. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

To update a document using Mongoose you need to use the yourDocumentModel.findByIdAndUpdate() (if it's one document at a time) function.

If you've installed all the packages as you'll need to do is call the async function to update the document in the DB

Comment: yeah, I already solved it. Idk if I wasn't clear in the question, what I meant is that I nedeed do insert a variable in the JSON.stringify but didn't know how

Comment: Ok I had not understood the question

Answer (score 0):

Solved it just by changing  `body: JSON.stringify( { target : '${input.value}'} )` for  `body: JSON.stringify( { [target] : '${input.value}'} )`